# How to ignore escaped parenthesis in a regex

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to extract some custom properties from a PDF with regex (I will use grep).

PDF custom properties are a key-value stored in this format:

```
<</key1(value1)/key2(value2)/key3(value3)>>
```

Parenthesis inside values are escaped:

```
/key4(outside \(inside\) outside)
```

I did the following regex to extract the value of a key:

```
grep -Po '(?<=key4\().*?(?=\))' "sample.txt"
```

However when applying it to the key4 (with parenthesis) it yields:

```
outside \(inside\
```

Because it stops in the first `)` (the one that is escaped) and not in the unescaped one.

**How can I ignore in my regex the escaped parenthesis?**

Thank you in advance.

PD: I am open to suggestions in sed or awk.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show clear, concise, testable sample input and expected output using truly representative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
(?<=key4\()[^\\()]*(?:\\[\S\s][^\\()]*)*(?=\))
```

https://regex101.com/r/B4qKdh/1

Expanded:

```
 (?<= key4\( )
 [^\\()]* 
 (?: \\ [\S\s] [^\\()]* )*
 (?= \) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `sed` solution like

```
sed 's/.*key4(\([^\()]*\(\\.[^\()]*\)*\)).*/\1/'
sed -E 's/.*key4\(([^\()]*(\\.[^\()]*)*)\).*/\1/'
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/sV0VPn).

**POSIX ERE pattern details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `key4\(` - `key(` literal string
- `\(  - a`(` char
- `([^\()]*(\\.[^\()]*)*)` - Group 1:

  - `[^\()]*` - 0 or more chars other than `\`, `(` and `)`
  - `(\\.[^\()]*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\\.` - a `\` followed with any 1 char
    - `[^\()]*`  - 0 or more chars other than `\`, `(` and `)`
- `\)` -  a `)` char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars

Note that POSIX BRE pattern just has literal and capturing parentheses escaping swapped (`(` in POSIX BRE matches a literal `(` char, it is not start of a capturing group).

The `\1` in the replacement part is the Group 1 placeholder and replaces the whole match with that group value.

Answer (score 0):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk '
    { gsub(/\\[(]/,"\n1"); gsub(/\\)/,"\n2") }
    match($0,/[/]key4[(][^)]+/) {
        $0 = substr($0,RSTART+6,RLENGTH-6)
        gsub(/\n1/,"\\("); gsub(/\n2/,"\\)")
        print
    }
' file
outside \(inside\) outside
```

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk '
    { gsub(/\\[(]/,"\n1"); gsub(/\\)/,"\n2") }
    match($0,/[/]key4[(]([^)]+)/,a) {
        $0 = a[1]
        gsub(/\n1/,"\\("); gsub(/\n2/,"\\)")
        print
    }
' file
outside \(inside\) outside
```

The above just replace `\(` and `\)` with strings that contain newlines (which cannot exist with newline separated records) `\n1` and `\n2`, then finds the match for key4, then puts the replacement strings back to their original values before printing.